# tkinter.Text that conforms to text size doesn't work with multiple instances

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, tkinter

I have a `tk.Text` class that conforms its height (not its width, that's determined by the parent) to the amount of text it has. It works with one instance of the text, but not multiple ones - it seems that the `self.resize` function is not called on the first textbox anymore. It might be because I don't fully understand the `bindtags` concept in tkinter yet. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
import tkinter as tk

class ResizedText(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        self.parent = parent
        self.container_container = tk.Frame(parent, bg="blue")
        self.container = tk.Frame(self.container_container, bg="red")
        super().__init__(self.container, *args, **kwargs)
        bindtags = list(self.bindtags())
        bindtags.insert(0, "custom")
        self.bindtags(tuple(bindtags))
        self.bind_class("custom", "<KeyRelease>", self.resize)
        self.container_container.bind("<Configure>", self.resize)
    def grid(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.container_container.grid(*args, **kwargs)
        self.container.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.container.grid_propagate(False)
        super().grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    def resize(self, event=None):
        self.container.config(width=self.container_container.winfo_width())
        if self.bbox("end-1c"):
            text_height = (self.bbox("end-1c")[1]+self.bbox("end-1c")[3])+4
            if text_height < 20: text_height = 20
        else: text_height = 20
        self.container.config(height=text_height)

GUI = tk.Tk()
f = ResizedText(GUI, wrap="word")
f.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew")
g = ResizedText(GUI, wrap="word")
g.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
GUI.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a single bindtag ("custom"), and trying to bind a unique binding for each window. In effect, each time you call `self.bind_class("custom", ...)` you are *redefining* the binding. That is because the tag is a shared resource, and it can only have one binding<sup>1</sup>.

Because your binding is tightly coupled to the instance, whatever widget is created last is the one that gets called whenever the event happens for any widget with that tag.

You need to either:

1. bind to the bind tag *once*, and have it call a function that can figure out which window the event is for (eg: perhaps it could use `event.widget` rather than `self`), or
2. create a custom bind tag for each widget, so that each binding is unique.

<sup>1</sup>That's not literally true, but for all intents and purposes it is. To describe why it's not would require a very lengthy answer, and it wouldn't get you any closer to your goal.

Comment: I want to create a binding in the _class_ to `<KeyRelease>`, but I also have to have an external binding to the _instance_, also to `<KeyRelease>`. Does this mean I still need to make a custom bindtag?

Comment: @claust: I'm not sure how to answer that in a tiny comment box. If you are going to bind an event to a specific instance (which is what the code in the question is doing), you'll need a custom bind tag for each instance. If your bound function can be rewritten to use `event.widget` rather than `self`, you only need a single bindtag that you will bind to a class method or global function.